# Changing the browser version in IE when closing F12 window

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I'm having an issue in IE browsers. I have developed an application which supports **IE 8+, chrome latest, safari 5+, Firefox latest**.

In my IE default version is IE 11 (edge). In edge it works as expected. Then I perform following steps.

1.)    Change the document mode from Edge to 10.

2.)    Close the F12 window.

3.)    Now, again open F12, that time IE5 is set in document mode by default.

4.)  web page is broken because some CSS and JS are not working in IE 5.

I have used this `meta` tag in `head` section.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

**Why default browser version is changing when closing F12 window?**

Or is this is an issue in IE ?

**Edit**: Content in head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: Do you have a proper HTML5 DTD and the x-ua is correctly placed?

Comment: @Teemu Please see edit.

Comment: Are you testing locally?  There's a setting in IE under `Compatibility View Settings` that defaults compatibility view for local/intranet sites.

Comment: @Barnett yes,  I'm testing this on local. But I saw the the fix you shared and did what it highlighted.